# Filter SQL Data to get latest for each alternate ID using MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to filter the data in my SQL so that I only have the latest row for each thickness where the IsReady field is true.

EDIT: I'm using MSSQL 2008 server for all who need to know

My data is like this:

```
+--+----------+-----------+----------+-------+
|ID|SupplierID|ThicknessID|DateTime  |IsReady|
+--+----------+-----------+----------+-------+
|01|1         |1          |01/01/1990|1      |
|02|1         |1          |01/01/2012|0      |
|03|1         |2          |01/01/1990|1      |
|04|1         |2          |01/01/2012|1      |
```

Based off this data provided, the SQL code should return the following:

```
+--+----------+-----------+----------+-------+
|ID|SupplierID|ThicknessID|DateTime  |IsReady|
+--+----------+-----------+----------+-------+
|01|1         |1          |01/01/1990|1      |
|04|1         |2          |01/01/2012|1      |
```

Hope this is enough information for you to understand, if not just comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Table t
WHERE IsReady=1
AND t.ID=(SELECT TOP 1 t2.ID
          FROM Table t2
          WHERE t2.IsReady=1
          AND t.ThicknessID=t2.ThicknessID
          ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE A,
              (SELECT ThicknessID,MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDateTime
               FROM TABLE 
               WHERE IsReady=1
               GROUP BY ThicknessID    
              ) B      
WHERE A.ThicknessID=B.ThicknessID AND
      A.MaxDateTime = B.DateTime;
```

Comment: Running this SQL returns an error: `No column name was specified for column 2 of 'B'.`

Comment: This just returns all of the items in my table. Cut's answer below seems to have worked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want separate rows for each `SupplierID`:

```
select t.ID,
    t.SupplierID,
    t.ThicknessID,
    t.[DateTime],
    t.IsReady
from MyTable t
inner join (
    select SupplierID,
        ThicknessID,
        max([DateTime]) as MaxDateTime
    from MyTable
    where IsReady = 1
    group by SupplierID,
        ThicknessID
    ) a on t.ThicknessID = a.ThicknessID
    and t.SupplierID = a.SupplierID
    and t.MaxDateTime = a.[DateTime]
```

Answer (score 0):

The selected query will work just fine. But this query will work much faster and will use less resources

```
select distinct (SupplierID, ThicknessID) * from
(
    select * from Table1 where IsReady = 1
    order by [DateTime] desc
)
```

I tried this and it is much more performant

Comment: This query returned me 2 errors.
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.`
`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.`

Comment: i am using hxtt so it worked on my database. I removed ON and put brakets around DateTime since datetime is a sql server reserved word